# How to find all repeating parts of one text python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text, for example:

```
a = '''
- Hello, this is a noname podcast and joining us today is Joe.
- Who's Joe? you would ask...
...
- Anyway, thank you for listening to the noname podcast. Special thanks to Joe, who was joining us today.
'''
```

Now I would like to find the repeating parts of this text of a sufficient length. For example, let us set the limit to 4 (so we are looking for strings longer than 4), so the name Joe is left out. So we should have:
`['noname podcast', 'joining us today']`.

I had an idea of using the `difflib`  for this, but it only works by comparing two texts, so I tried feeding it the same text two times and picking sequences which will appear more than twice with `difflib.SequenceMatcher`, but it just returns one sequence which is the whole text (not very surprisingly, really).

What would be the correct way to approach this?

Comment: If you set the limit to 4 you will still find a lot of matches for `" Joe"` with a space at the start

Comment: Have you looked into using [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

Comment: Could you clarify what is your notion of repeating parts? Just repeated words of length 4 or lower in your example?  I assume you want to operate at the word level so you'd need some sort of splitter on your string, right?

Comment: @mousetail True, but this is just an example, I am actually looking for sequences of 50 or longer for which this would not be an issue

Comment: @Tzane Sure, but I can't think of an implementation. How do I get the sequence which I match to? Do I just add chars to string untill re spots any duplicates? This would be quite unoptimal, as I will have to search through the whole text for every character.

Comment: @Luis Well, I have a text where there are a lot of repeated long lines which are repeated because of some law. For example "We also have to add that this is not a financial advice in any shape or form, all the parties continue at their own risk". This is unnessesary information and I would like to get rid of it. The limit is 4 and above, just because I don't want the single words to match. The actual limit is more like 50 and above, but it was too long for the example.

Comment: @Ramesh Sure, how would you like me to update it?

Comment: @Ramesh Sorry, not sure if I understand you correctly. There are no repeating paragraphs in the example, hence I have only listed the stings. Besides, if it was multiline, the difference would only be the ```\n```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248903/discussion-between-user9102437-and-ramesh).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some proposal. This operates at the word level using a simple split but you can tune this to sentences or any other split depending on your interests. Also importantly, you'd need some preprocessing (I just cleaned for dots but in a large text more should be done).

```
a = '''
- Hello, this is a noname podcast and joining us today is Joe.
- Who's Joe? you would ask...
- Anyway, thank you for listening to the noname podcast. Special thanks to Joe, who was joining us today.
'''

mylist=a.split()

# Some preprocessing:
mylist=[i.replace('.','') for i in mylist  ]

from collections import Counter
my_dict=Counter(mylist)


[i for i in mylist if len(i)>4 and my_dict[i]>1]
```

Comment: This only returns singular words, and I am looking for sentences. Words is what I am trying to avoid here.

Comment: Yeah, as I said i am not sure what your splitting criteria is, but with that code you can adapt it. In your example your desired result is 'noname podcast' which is a bigram but not a sentence. The same code scaled up should give you repeated objects that depend on how you split your string.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot adapt it because the whole reason I have this question is because I don't have the splitting criteria. It can be a sentence, it can be a paragraph, it can be a page or just a few words. I don't know.

Comment: Then I can't think of any solution. Be aware that if you as a human does not even have a criterium on what to search, it is hard to make a program understand what to check duplicates on... You can do robustness with different splitters but that's all I can imagine...

Answer (score 0):

using nltk

```
from collections import Counter
import nltk

a = '''
- Hello, this is a noname podcast and joining us today is Joe.
- Who's Joe? you would ask...
...
- Anyway, thank you for listening to the noname podcast. Special thanks to Joe, who was joining us today.
'''

# function to replace words
def word_remover(string, noise_list):
    for v in noise_list:
        string = string.replace(v, "")
    return string


data_split = nltk.word_tokenize(a)
repeat_words = [k for k, v in Counter(data_split).items() if v >= 2 and len(k) > 1]
get_index = [data_split.index(i) for i in repeat_words]

find_seq = []
for i in get_index:
    if i == get_index[-1]:
        break
    if i + 1 in get_index:
        find_seq.append(data_split[i])
        find_seq.append(data_split[i + 1])

duplicates = [i for i in repeat_words if i in find_seq or len(i) > 3]
print(duplicates)
print(word_remover(a, duplicates))

>>>>['noname', 'podcast', 'joining', 'us', 'today']

>>>>- Hello, this is a   and    is Joe.
>>>>- Who's Joe? you would ask...
>>>>...
>>>>- Anyway, thank you for listening to the  . Special thanks to Joe, who was   .
```

Comment: This is a cool solution, but it will delete works like `noname` and `podcast` even if they are out of the sequence. For example I would like to remove "you are listening to a noname podcast" from a text like this: "you are listening to a noname podcast and our special guest today is noname". We will get "and our special guest today is"

Comment: what you asked for is quite hard and may be impossible without any sequence for splitting.